# Converting millisecond to timestamp

Tags: python

1634515205001 converted to date & timer is : Mon Oct 18 2021 00:00:05

I attempt to convert 1634515205001 to date and time using :

import datetime

```
dt1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(
                    str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1634515205001 / 1000)),
                    "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f").strftime(
                    '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')

print('dt1' , dt1)
```

which prints :

```
dt1 2021-10-18T01:00:05Z
```

Why is a division by 1000 `(1634515205001 / 1000)` required ? Using :

```
dt1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(
    str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1634515205001)),
    "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f").strftime(
    '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')

print('dt1', dt1)
```

renders :

```
    str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1634515205001)),
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Does `fromtimestamp` not accept millisecond as parameter ?

Comment: Note that datetime.fromtimestamp() returns a datatime object so don't need to reparse it as a string with datetime.strptime(). Can just call strftime() on the result of fromtimestamp() directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [datetime.fromtimestamp()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) function converts time in seconds (not millseconds) so epoch times in milliseconds need to be converted to seconds (divide by 1000).

This call is trying to compute 1634515205001 seconds since 1-Jan-1970 which is year 53765, and raises an exception.

```
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(1634515205001)
```

Can get the number of expected digits for fromtimestamp() for the current time by calling [time.time()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time) to get the time in seconds for the current time.

```
print(time.time())
```

**Output:**

```
1649365827.417279     <= 10 digits before the decimal place
```

**Time zones**

The function *fromtimestamp()* is timezone aware so if the timezone argument is not provided then date time is converted to the local time zone. If the timezone is not specified and the timestamp time zone is different than the local time zone then the converted date time will be computed incorrectly. Below the local time zone is UTC-4.

```
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(1634515205.001, tz=timezone.utc)
print(dt) # => 2021-10-18 00:00:05.001000+00:00

dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(1634515205.001)
print(dt) # => 2021-10-17 20:00:05.001000
```

> Warning: Because naive `datetime` objects are treated by many `datetime` methods as
> local times, it is preferred to use aware datetimes to represent times
> in UTC. As such, the recommended way to create an object representing
> a specific timestamp in UTC is by calling
> `datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp, tz=timezone.utc)`.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, **yes**, Python takes seconds instead of milliseconds when computing the dates.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp), `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp` function definition says:

> Return the local date corresponding to the POSIX timestamp, such as is returned by time.time().

The `POSIX timestamp` is the number of seconds that have elapsed since the 1st of January from 1970 (UTC).

So yes, `fromtimestamp` does not accept milliseconds, since POSIX timestamps are defined as seconds

If you are working with milliseconds, you have also the alternative to use something like:

```
datetime = datetime(1970, 1, 1) + timedelta(milliseconds=1634515205001)
```